# ES6/ES2015 object destructuring and changing target variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

How can I rename the target during object destructing?

```
const b = 6;
const test = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const {a, b as c} = test; // <-- `as` does not seem to be valid in ES6/ES2015
// a === 1
// b === 6
// c === 2
```

Comment: Have you tried `{a, b: c} = test`?

Comment: `{b as c}` is for ES6 import syntax, which is very much _not_ destructuring FYI. Misunderstanding that difference can lead to confusion around how modules work.

Comment: Related: [Object destructuring with property names that are not valid variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36577568/1048572)

Comment: Related: [Destructuring and rename property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57065348/1048572)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can assign new variable names, like shown in this [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Simple_example_2)

```js
var o = { p: 42, q: true };

// Assign new variable names
var { p: foo, q: bar } = o;

console.log(foo); // 42
console.log(bar); // true
```

---

So, in your case, the code will be like this

```js
const b = 6;
const test = { a: 1, b: 2 };
let { a, b: c } = test;
console.log(a, b, c); // 1 6 2
```

[Online Babel Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20b%20%3D%206%3B%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%7D%3B%0Alet%20%7Ba%2C%20b%3A%20c%7D%20%3D%20test%3B%0Aconsole.log(a%2C%20b%2C%20c)%3B)

Comment: Can the *renaming* process use the current variable name and add something to it? like a transformation function. I want to construct a dynamic re-named name

Comment: @vsync Unfortunately that is not possible.