# Destructure res.headers

Tags: javascript, get, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure the response.headers of my axios.get request because I only need the x-csrf-token. It is always the second position. This is the how the res.headers response looks

```
{
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'x-csrf-token': '17hoqAWEwVmcN32wYgN9WA==',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      dataserviceversion: '2.0',
      'c4c-odata-response-time': '1195  ms',
      date: 'Fri, 28 Feb 2020 10:06:55 GMT',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close, Transfer-Encoding',
      'set-cookie': [
        'sap-usercontext=sap-client=041; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure',
        '
      ],
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains'
    }
```

I tried

```
let{a,b} = res.headers;
      console.log(b);
```

and

```
let[,b] = res.headers;
      console.log(b);
```

But I just get: undefined is not a function

Comment: the properties in the destructuing syntax (ie: a and b), need to be properties in your header object. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object destructuring with property names that are not valid variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577568/object-destructuring-with-property-names-that-are-not-valid-variable-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is always the second position

That doesn't matter with object destructuring. You use the key, not the position.

To get it:

```
const {'x-csrf-token': token} = res.headers;
```

or

```
const {headers: {'x-csrf-token': token}] = res;
```

Live Example:

```js
const res = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'x-csrf-token': '17hoqAWEwVmcN32wYgN9WA==',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    dataserviceversion: '2.0',
    'c4c-odata-response-time': '1195  ms',
    date: 'Fri, 28 Feb 2020 10:06:55 GMT',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    connection: 'close, Transfer-Encoding',
    'set-cookie': [
      'sap-usercontext=sap-client=041; path=/;HttpOnly;Secure'
    ],
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains'
  }
};
const {'x-csrf-token': token} = res.headers;
console.log(token);
const {headers: {'x-csrf-token': token2}} = res;
console.log(token2);
```

The key here is that destructuring syntax is the converse of an object literal, it's just that instead of `key: value` meaning "put `value` in for property `key`", it means "take the value from property `key` and put it in `value`" — that is, information in a literal flows right to left, but information in destructuring flows left to right. Here's a figure from Chapter 7 of my new book (see my profile for details);

[image]

In this particular case, destructuring doesn't buy you much vs.

```
const token = res.headers['x-csrf-token'];
```