# Importing Multiple Modules At Once in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module

I would like to import the following modules in NodeJS

```
const path = require("path");
const { join } = require("path");
const getDirName = require("path").dirname;
```

How can I consolidate these imports into a single require statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6/ES2015 object destructuring and changing target variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904523/es6-es2015-object-destructuring-and-changing-target-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reason why you're importing path three times?  Just import it once and use it from there.  If you need to use the `join` function, just invoke it via `path.join()`, or use `path.dirname()`

Otherwise, do it like so:

`const path = require('path');
const { join, dirname } = path;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly braces and import the exact name of the module

> const {join, dirname} = require("path")