# vue.js nuxt.js how to call multiple api url call in axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I am trying to get Multiple API URLs call in Vue.

I tried a single API URL call, and it worked. When I tried to use multiple calls, it did not work.

And it worked for the following:

```js
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  let { data } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
  return {
      Userslist: data,
  };
},
computed: {
  UserCount () {
    return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;
  },
}
```

```html
<p>{{ UserCount }}</p>
```

But not this:

```js
 async asyncData({ $axios }) {
   let { Usersdata } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
   return {
     Userslist: Usersdata ,
   };
 },
 computed: {
   UserCount () {
     return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;
   },
 }
```

```html
 <p>{{ UserCount }}</p>
```

My multiple API URL call code:

```html
<p>{{ UserCount }}</p> 
<p>{{ BusinessCount}}</p> 
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Userslist: [],
      Businesslist: [],
    };
  },

  async asyncData({ $axios }) {
    let { dataBusiness } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
    let { dataUsers } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
    return {
      Businesslist: dataBusiness,
      Userslist: dataUsers,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    BusinessCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.Businesslist).length;
    },
    UserCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

I tried to `console.log` it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$axios.get()` returns a [`Response`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) object, where the response data is stored in `data`. You're missing the property [renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904639/6277151) in your destructuring:

```js
// DON'T DO THIS:
//let { dataBusiness } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
//let { dataUsers } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");

let { data: dataBusiness } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
let { data: dataUsers } = await $axios.$get("/Userslist");
```

Also, if `Businesslist` and `Userslist` are arrays, you could use [`Array.prototype.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to get the number of items in the array (instead of `Object.keys(Businesslist).length`, etc):

```js
computed: {
  BusinessCount() {
    // DON'T DO THIS
    //return Object.keys(this.Businesslist).length;

    return this.Businesslist.length;
  },
  UserCount() {
    // DON'T DO THIS
    //return Object.keys(this.Userslist).length;

    return this.Userslist.length;
  },
},
```