# useSWR for mutiple requests

Tags: javascript, next.js, swr

I'd like to implement useSWR in my web app and remove axios from the project, but I don't see how I can use SWR multiple times on the same page.
I thought I could use two hooks:

`const { userData, userError } = useSWR(url, fetcher)`

`const { coinData, coinError } = useSWR(url,fetcher)`

but that doesn't work. (I guess you need to use `{ data, error }`)

This is the code I currently have, but I'd like to make another get request to my database with SWR.

```
  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coinURL}`,
    fetcher
  );

  if (error) {
    return <div>failed</div>;
  }
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return <div>{data.name}</div>;
```

What's the best way to make multiple requests on the same page with useSWR?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6/ES2015 object destructuring and changing target variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904523/es6-es2015-object-destructuring-and-changing-target-variable)

Answer (score 11):

try

```
const { data : userData, error: userError } = useSWR(url, fetcher)

const { data : coinData, error: coinError } = useSWR(url,fetcher)
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you are re-using the same constant variable names. You can just store the result of `useSWR` in an object:

```
 const res1 = useSWR(..);
 const res2 = useSWR(..);
```

And then reference each property like normal: `res1.loading`, etc.