# What does export const { x: y} = z; do?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm really confused by the following statement in an index.ts:

```
import z from 'path/to/z';
export const { x: y } = z;
```

What does the second line actually export and how does the value of z correlate with it? Also, what purpose does this kind of export serve?

Comment: This exports a const `y` which is a renamed property `x` from the object `z`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an `export` declaration with a `const` [destructuring pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34904523/1048572). `y` is the variable being declared, which is initialised with the `x` property of `z`.

It could (and perhaps should) be written as the equivalent

```
export const y = z.x;
```

Comment: The code in the question definitely falls under the _"too fancy for its own good"_ banner